# passing javascript variables between functions

Tags: javascript

I am a complete JS noob, so bear with me please.

I got a simple JS to query yahoo stock price, which is working great, however for some reason i cannot pass the result variable to another function, where i would like to perform some other calculations with it. I pasted the simplified version here.

If someone could help i would appreciate it, so i couldn't figure this out, all morning. :(

Thanks!

```js
var result = "0";

function onBodyLoad(){

 getQuote();
 
 var balance = "100";
 var leverage = balance/result;
  
 $("#leverage_result").text(leverage);   
 
}

function getQuote(){

    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    var symbol = $("#symbol").val();
    symbol = "^GSPC";

    var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");
 
    $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
        .done(function (data) {   
        result = parseInt(data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
    });
   
}
```

```html
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<div id='leverage_result'>No Price</div>
</body>
```

Comment: well, it should, however there is a mess-up around how i am storing the result variable in the second function, outside that getJSON call it cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're banging your head against a wall here because you're treating asynchronous code as if it were synchronous. When you do `$.getJSON` the code does not stop to wait for the result to arrive, it continues. Therefore, in your `onBodyLoad` function, the lines after `getQuote` are executed *immediately* and not after the result arrives from the request you issue inside the `getQuote` function.

What you want to do is run your code after you get your results back from the server, and therefore you could use a callback:

```
function onBodyLoad(){

     getQuote(function(result) {
         var balance = "100";
         var leverage = balance/result;

         $("#leverage_result").text(leverage);            
     });

}

function getQuote(callback){

    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    var symbol = $("#symbol").val();
    symbol = "^GSPC";

    var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");

    $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
    .done(function (data) {   
        result = parseInt(data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);

        callback(result);
    });

}
```

What's happening is that I'm creating an anonymous function that receives a `result` as its only parameter, and uses it do the operations you need to after you receive your data from the remote server. This function is passed to your `getQuote` function and called only after the `$.getJSON` has completed. A more elegant solution would be to use promises, but this should get you going.

Oh, and avoid global variables. 99.9% of the time they can be avoided because a solution exists where they are not required.

Comment: Thanks, what you are saying makes sense, i was sure my code is not optimal, JS is far from my strongsuit. :)

for some reason the result variable still doesnt reach the second function: http://jsfiddle.net/RU8Jq/807/

Any idea what i am messing up? :/

Comment: The id is `result`, not `leverage_result`!

Comment: I am crying, thank you very much, i wish i could treat you to a beer or something, nevertheless i upvoted your comment!thank you very much once again!!!! :)